# Flutter sqflite getting single data from user database SQL

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

```
Future getSingleUser(int id) async {
    Database db = await getDataBase();

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> user =
        await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM userInfos WHERE $columnId = $id");
    if (user.isNotEmpty) {
      return UserModel(
          id: int.parse(user[0]["id"]),
          name: user[0]["name"],
          password: user[0]["password"],
          gender: user[0]["gender"]);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I want to get single user that I entered the Id in the method but I get an empty user.

```
Future<List<UserModel>> getAllUsers() async {
    Database db = await getDataBase();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> usersMap = await db.query(tableName);

    return List.generate(usersMap.length, (index) {
      return UserModel(
          id: int.parse(usersMap[index]["id"]),
          name: usersMap[index]["name"],
          password: usersMap[index]["password"],
          gender: usersMap[index]["gender"]);
    });
  }
```

I did change this method to get me that goal to get single user but it still doesn't do that and returns nothing - not even an error.

Comment: Try using `db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM userInfos WHERE id = $id")` instead.